# Fetch shopify products based on product tags

Tags: graphql, shopify, product, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working on fetching Shopify products based on the product tag. I did the below code for it and it's working fine when I put the `AND` condition, But it douses not work with the `OR` condition. It shows products where a tag appears in text content.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an expression like that you're searching for tags containg OR, you should put the boolean expression out, like this

```
{ 
   products(query:"tag:Blue OR tag:Pink"){
      ...
```

Comment: does anybody know where this is documented? can i do something similar for collection ids and product type and such?

Comment: okay, i found *some* relevant info: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/search-syntax